# How can I return a string from a cordova custom plugin

Tags: java, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

While creating a custom plugin in cordova the return type of the execute methode is Boolean but for my application I want some String type to be returned that I can use in my javascript. But as the return type is Boolean, I am not able to do so.

Is there any way I can return some value from that execute method??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Android and iOS, here's how you'd send a string from native back to the JS layer in your Cordova app:

**Android (Java)**

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        String myString = "Some string";
        callbackContext.success(myString);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**iOS (Objective-C)**

```
@implementation MyPlugin

- (void) myAction:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    NSString* myString = @"Some string";

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:myString];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

**Plugin bridge (Javascript)**

```
MyPlugin = {
    myAction: function(success, error){
        cordova.exec(success, error, "MyPlugin", "myAction", []);
    }
}
module.exports = MyPlugin;
```

**Your app (Javascript)**

```
function success(myString){
    alert(myString);
}

function error(error){
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}

MyPlugin.myAction(success, error);
```

Comment: Best answer I've seen! Thanks!